# Monotouch.Dialog element styling effecting background view

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am having some problems trying to style a monotouch.dialog.

I am setting the background dialog like

```
public override void LoadView ()
    {
        base.LoadView ();
        TableView.BackgroundView = null;
        TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/Background/bg-app"));
```

The section title looks ok however each of the elements looks like its recreating the background.

What is the easiest (and best) way to only display the white frame and not to recreate the background? I want the look of a single background image with the dialog appearing over the background

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting an image the full size of the table view -

```
TableView.BackgroundView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("image-size-of-table-view.png"));
```